# Ошибка при запуске приложения на Spring Boot 3.2.1 с Flyway

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, spring-boot, flyway

При попытке запустить приложение падает с ошибкой :

```
2024-01-17T00:04:40.030+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Demo1Application        : Starting Demo1Application using Java 17.0.7 with PID 15328 (D:\Programer\JavaProject\demo1\target\classes started by Ekyd9 in D:\Programer\JavaProject\demo1)
2024-01-17T00:04:40.033+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Demo1Application        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-17T00:04:40.738+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-01-17T00:04:40.779+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 34 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
2024-01-17T00:04:41.181+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-01-17T00:04:41.189+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-01-17T00:04:41.189+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.17]
2024-01-17T00:04:41.233+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-01-17T00:04:41.233+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1153 ms
2024-01-17T00:04:41.260+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-01-17T00:04:41.437+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:file:~/data/demo user=SA
2024-01-17T00:04:41.438+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-01-17T00:04:41.447+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:file:~/data/demo'
2024-01-17T00:04:41.487+03:00  WARN 15328 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Circular depends-on relationship between 'flyway' and 'entityManagerFactory'
2024-01-17T00:04:41.487+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-01-17T00:04:41.696+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-01-17T00:04:41.698+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-01-17T00:04:41.706+03:00  INFO 15328 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-17T00:04:41.719+03:00 ERROR 15328 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Circular depends-on relationship between 'flyway' and 'entityManagerFactory'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1232) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.example.demo.Demo1Application.main(Demo1Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
```

зависимости pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo1</name>
    <description>demo1</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>10.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Установки application.yaml:

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:~/data/demo
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
      settings.trace: false
      settings.web-allow-others: false
  flyway:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:~/data/demo
    user: sa
    password: password
    schemas: demo
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    baseline-on-migrate: true
```

Путь до файла миграции : `src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__Init.sql`
Файл миграции:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id      uuid primary key,
    name    varchar not null,
    surname varchar not null
);
```

При запуске приложения без зависимости FlyWay, приложение работает корректно.
При указании для зависимости FlyWay конкрентной версии `<version>9.16.0</version>` ситуация не меняется.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась в зависимости в файле application.yaml :
`defer-datasource-initialization: true`
замена настройки на :
`defer-datasource-initialization: false` или удаление данного поля решило проблему.
Подробнее о зависимостях по ссылке : ["How-to" Guides](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html)